# How autofill all rows between two dates in excel with the second date as the incrementing limit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I am trying to figure out take one cell.... say A1 and put a date in it.... then move down several thousand rows and give another date 3 months later... and have it auto fill the dates between the two...

```
      (M/D/Y)

            COL A
  Row1      1/5/2012   (january)
   -
   -
   -
   -
Row 3250    3/5/2012    (only 3 months later but thousands of rows)
```

I want it ONLY to increment by day... But to do it evenly.... Like in blocks so:

number of days the same = rows (3250... or whatever it may be) / days (90)

Count the number of rows between.... then the number of days... then divide them up so that there are even blocks of days between... Maybe just putting the remainder if any on the end?

Comment: How many rows are you using per day..?

Comment: thats what i need to figure out... I think?! If you divide those two numbers (3250rows/90days) it would tell you the number that I would like to increment by.... I believe?

basically the rows are publish dates for articles on a website... I would like to publish them evenly over 3 months... even though there are thousands or hundreds or articles (number of articles may vary)

Comment: I have made some progress...

If you divide the number of rows/days it gives you the number of rows that should contain the same date...

So now I just need some formula or excel method to take a start date and copy it / fill it down for the number of days from (rows/90days)... Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If your first date is in A1 and last date in A31, this should do the trick

```
=INT((ROW(A2)-ROW(A$1))/(ROW(A$31)-ROW(A$1))*INT((A$31-A$1)/90))*90+A$1
```

Where you can replace 90 (both occurences) by the number of days between each step.

Answer (score 1):

The Fill Series command will fill in the gaps. Highlight the range including the first and last date. On the Home tab, in the Editing group choose the Fill command and Series. Just check the Trend box and click OK, and it should work out the steps required to fit.

Answer (score -1):

1. Fill next row
2. Select this two rows
3. Drag to corner and spread it to your date

This works with any numerable objects - "a,b,c...", "1,2,3..""p1,p2,p3.." etc.
Also works with different formulas with dinamic or static values

Comment: whatever, just formula not enought for filling cells/rows. It must be or my way with cells selection or VB-macros